# Scroll bar doesn't appear when attempting to create QScrollArea with PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qwidget

I'm using Pyside2 to create a simple UI. I'm very new to Qt (and Python in general). I have been able to make my scroll areas in Qt work with simpler setups, but I have not been able to get the following setup to show any scrollbar, nor does it let me resize my window. The height is always fixed.

I want everything within the main layout to be scrollable if the contents go beyond the screen/window boundaries.

I also don't want the Qt window to always have the height of the contents (I suspect this is because I haven't defined something properly in QVBoxLayout).

Thank you very much for any help and suggestions!

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self._widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self._window.resize(200, 200)
        self._window.setWindowTitle('My Scrollbar Test')
        self._window.setCentralWidget(self._widget)

        # Create a box layout
        self._mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._widget)
        self._mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self._mainLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self._widget.setLayout(self._mainLayout)

        # Create a scroll area
        self._scrollAreaWidget = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()

        # Assign a QWidget to the scroll widget
        self._contentWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self._scrollAreaWidget.setWidget(self._contentWidget)
        self._scrollAreaWidget.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self._layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._contentWidget)
        self._contentWidget.setLayout(self._layout)

        # Add tabs
        self._tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self._tabWidget.addTab(self.createTabOneLayout(), 'Test 1')
        self._tabWidget.addTab(self.createTabOneLayout(), 'Test 2')
        self._tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)
        self._layout.addWidget(self._tabWidget)

        # Add widget containing scroll area to the main layout
        self._mainLayout.addWidget(self._contentWidget)

        self._window.show()

    # Tab function
    def createTabOneLayout(self):
        self._newTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self._tabLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._newTab)       

        # Add buttons
        for a in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            self._newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(a)
            self._newButton.setFixedSize(50,50)
            self._tabLayout.addWidget(self._newButton)

        return self._newTab

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the `self._contentWidget` to the main layout, because that is part of the scroll area, you should add the scroll area to it instead.

You should add the following line:

```
self._mainLayout.addWidget(self._scrollAreaWidget)
```

and remove this:

```
self._mainLayout.addWidget(self._contentWidget)
```

Consider that your code is more complex than it should be:

- if you only have one scroll area and no other "sibling" widget, you should set that as central widget;
- if you only have one QTabWidget in the scroll area, you should set it as main widget for the scroll area;

Also consider that the PyQt convention is to use subclasses for the main widget (the top level window), so it's better to directly inherit from QMainWindow for your `Test` class. This makes the code more clean and also allows easier overriding of existing methods.

Also, if you have a function that dynamically creates new elements, setting instance attributes for them is completely useless (and might lead to confusion): the new widgets are created with a parent (or their ownership is taken by a parent), so there's no need for a persistent reference (`self.someObject` instead of a local `someObject`) that would be overwritten anyway whenever the function is called again. This is valid for both functions and `for` loops.

```py
class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Scrollbar Test')

        # Create a scroll area
        self._scrollAreaWidget = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._scrollAreaWidget)

        # Add tabs
        self._tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self._tabWidget.addTab(self.createTabOneLayout(), 'Test 1')
        self._tabWidget.addTab(self.createTabOneLayout(), 'Test 2')
        self._tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)

        self._scrollAreaWidget.setWidget(self._tabWidget)
        self._scrollAreaWidget.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.show()

    def createTabOneLayout(self):
        newTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        tabLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(newTab)       

        # Add buttons
        for a in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(a)
            newButton.setFixedSize(50,50)
            tabLayout.addWidget(newButton)

        return newTab
```